# onvif gsoap event related

Tags: gsoap, onvif

We are currently developing the onvif protocol using gsoap 2.8.80. I can't find an answer in the event part, so I'm asking this question. If you click the event in Onvif Device Manager and check the data in Wireshark, GetEventPropertiesRequest comes and sends GetEventPropertiesRequest again instead of GetEventProertiesResponse with http 200 OK. Could you please suggest a way for me to deal with this problem? thank you.

```
fprintf(stderr, "__tev__GetEventProperties Entered\n");

    int ret = 0;
    
    ret = check_onvif_authentication(soap);
    if (SOAP_OK != ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "check_onvif_authentication: no authorization\n");
        return ret;
    }


    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__sizeTopicNamespaceLocation = 1;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->TopicNamespaceLocation = (char **)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char *));
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->TopicNamespaceLocation[0] = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH + 1);
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->TopicNamespaceLocation[0], 0, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH + 1);
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->TopicNamespaceLocation[0], "http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/topics/topicns.xml");
    
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet = (struct wstop__TopicSetType *)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(struct wstop__TopicSetType)); 
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->documentation = (struct wstop__Documentation *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct wstop__Documentation));
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->documentation = NULL;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__size = 2;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any = (char **)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char *) * tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__size);
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any[0] = (char*)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char) * 1024);
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any[0], 0, sizeof(char) * 1024);
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any[1] = (char*)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char) * 1024); 
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any[1], 0, sizeof(char) * 1024); 
//      tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop2__TopicSet->__any[2] = (char*)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char) * 1024);        
//      memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop2__TopicSet->__any[2], 0, sizeof(char) * 1024);    
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any[0], "<tns1:VideoAnalytics><tns1:MotionDetection><tns1:Motion wstop:topic=\"true\"><tt:MessageDescription><tt:Source><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"VideoAnalyticsConfigurationToken\" Type=\"tt:ReferenceToken\"/></tt:Source><tt:Data><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"ObjectId\" Type=\"tt:ObjectRefType\"/></tt:Data></tt:MessageDescription></tns1:Motion></tns1:MotionDetection></tns1:VideoAnalytics>");
//      strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop2__TopicSet->__any[1], "<tns1:Device><tns1:Trigger><tns1:DigitalInput wstop:topic=\"true\"><tt:MessageDescription><tt:Source><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"Index\" Type=\"xsd.int\"/></tt:Source><tt:Data><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"Level\" Type=\"xsd.int\"/></tt:Data></tt:DigitalInput></tns1:Motion></tns1:Trigger></tns1:Device>"); 
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wstop__TopicSet->__any[1], "<tns1:RuleEngine><CellMotionDetector><Motion wstop:topic=\"true\"><tt:MessageDescription><tt:Source><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"VideoSourceConfigurationToken\" Type=\"tt.ReferenceToken\"/><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"VideoAnalyticsConfigurationToken\" Type=\"tt.ReferenceToken\"/><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"Rule\" Type=\"tt.xsd.string\"/></tt:Source><tt:Data><tt:SimpleItemDescription Name=\"IsMotion\" Type=\"xsd.boolean\"/></tt:Data></tt:MessageDescription></tns1:Motion></CellMotionDetector></tns1:RuleEngine>");      

    
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__sizeTopicExpressionDialect = 2;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect = (char **)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char *) * 2); 
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[0] = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, URI_LENGTH + 1); 
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[1] = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, URI_LENGTH + 1); 
//      tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[2] = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, URI_LENGTH + 1);   
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[0], 0, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH +1);
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[1], 0, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH +1);      
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[0], "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/topicExpression/ConcreteSet");
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->wsnt__TopicExpressionDialect[1], "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1/TopicExpression/ConcreteSet"); 

    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__sizeMessageContentFilterDialect = 1;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentFilterDialect = (char **)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char *));
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentFilterDialect[0] = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH + 1);
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentFilterDialect[0], 0, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH +1);   
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentFilterDialect[0], "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/messageContentFilter/ItemFilter");
    
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__sizeProducerPropertiesFilterDialect = 0;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->ProducerPropertiesFilterDialect = NULL;
    
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__sizeMessageContentSchemaLocation = 1;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentSchemaLocation = (char **)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char *));
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentSchemaLocation[0] = (char *)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH + 1);
    memset(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentSchemaLocation[0], '\0', sizeof(char) * URI_LENGTH + 1);
    strcpy(tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->MessageContentSchemaLocation[0], "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd");
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__size = 0;
    tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->__any = NULL;
    
    
    return SOAP_OK;
```

This is my xml data seen with wireshark

```
    <?xml
        version="1.0"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        ?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:chan="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex"
        xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
        xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
        xmlns:saml1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
        xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
        xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"
        xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"
        xmlns:wsrf_bf2="http://tempuri.org/wsrf_bf2.xsd"
        xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1"
        xmlns:wsrf_r2="http://tempuri.org/wsrf_r2.xsd"
        xmlns:ns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl"
        xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"
        xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl"
        xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2"
        xmlns:tima="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl"
        xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl"
        xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <wsa5:Action>
                http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventPortType/GetEventPropertiesRequest
                </wsa5:Action>
            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <tev:GetEventPropertiesResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been fighting the same problem, and my workaround was to just go and set the `wsa__Action` to the value the conformance tests are expecting, e.g.

```
// for some reason gsoap puts the request action into the response, but we need the response action
soap->header->wsa__Action = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventPortType/GetEventPropertiesResponse";
```

It's not particularly elegant, but it works - for now.